# SVN updates, but has r1 files instead of the new r2

Tags: svn, commit

I created an SVN repo locally and imported some files to it. I then made my first round of changes, added a file, and committed:

```
?> svn add Makefile
?> svn commit -m "Turned ssh business into a class, added primary content to main, added Makefile, and filled in usage()\nCOMPILES"
?> svn update
```

So I actually needed to delete all the old files for update to not say `an unversioned file of the same name already exists` (actually just moved them elsewhere).  But after I did update the log reads:

```
?> svn log file:///home/vlad417//svnrepos/RemoteCMD/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | vlad417 | 2012-12-03 22:29:35 -0500 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012) | 1 line

Turned ssh business into a class, added primary content to main, added Makefile, and filled in usage()\nCOMPILES
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | vlad417 | 2012-12-03 21:15:24 -0500 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012) | 1 line

Initial framework and comments
------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, the files that were placed in the folder from the repo by `svn update` were the revision 1 files, but the Makefile added in revision 2 is all there.

A) If I committed changes, why weren't they updated to what was committed?
B) Why was the file added in r2 fine, but the rest were updated to what was imported originally (as revision 1)?

So, if I do the following...

```
$> svn log -q -v
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r2 | vlad417 | 2012-12-03 22:29:35 -0500 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012)
Changed paths:
   A /Makefile
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r1 | vlad417 | 2012-12-03 21:15:24 -0500 (Mon, 03 Dec 2012)
Changed paths:
   A /RemoteCMD.cpp
   A /RemoteCMD.h
   A /sshlib.cpp
   A /sshlib.h
------------------------------------------------------------------------
$> svn ls -v -R file:///home/vlad417/svnrepos/RemoteCMD/
      2 vlad417               Dec 03 22:29 ./
      2 vlad417           201 Dec 03 22:29 Makefile
      1 vlad417           555 Dec 03 21:15 RemoteCMD.cpp
      1 vlad417           218 Dec 03 21:15 RemoteCMD.h
      1 vlad417           809 Dec 03 21:15 sshlib.cpp
      1 vlad417           316 Dec 03 21:15 sshlib.h
```

I see now that revision 2 only added the Makefile. So A) still stands: Why didn't the 4 modified files get committed?

I was keeping my files in independent folders, one for each of my revisions during experimentation. After the clean `update` above, I copied the files from the r2 folder into this version controlled folder.  To my surprise a commit after this was successful. After another update the log reads revision 3's message and the files are indeed the changes I made...unfortunately all the calls to `help` buried my very first commands, so I can't see my mistakes =(

Comment: Is your old copy the latest revision ? I mean are you having the updated revision in your local ?

Comment: Vlad, check and show `svn lon -q -v` and `svn ls -v -R file:///home/vlad417//svnrepos/RemoteCMD/` : your wording of the question is slightly ambiguous